# Is there a way to carry out a decreasing balance subtraction in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres query that returns a table like the one below:

```
_______________________________________________________
|  id  |  item  |  amount  |  paid  |  apply_payment  |
+------+--------+----------+--------+-----------------+
|  1   | item 1 |     500  |     0  |     15,000      |
|  2   | item 2 |  20,000  |  3000  |     15,000      |
|  3   | item 3 |   7,000  |     0  |     15,000      |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

According to the above table, a "client" makes a payment towards items purchased, in this case, one 15,000 payment. I'd like to make deductions on a reducing balance on the 15,000 such that:

- On the first item, `15,000` pays for the entire `item 1` of `500` leaving a balance of `14,500`
- On `item 2` that costs `20,000` there was a previous payment of `3000` so the `14,500` above goes into the `17,000` balance here.
- `item 3` stays unpaid since there's no balance above.

All in all, the results could look like this:

```
__________________________________________________________________________
|  id  |  item  |  amount  |  paid  |  apply_payment  |  amount_applied  |
+------+--------+----------+--------+-----------------+------------------+
|  1   | item 1 |     500  |     0  |     15,000      |       500        |
|  2   | item 2 |  20,000  |  3000  |     14,500      |    14,500        |
|  3   | item 3 |   7,000  |     0  |          0      |         0        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve the `amount_applied` above in postgres? **Notice that the `apply_payment` in the second (desired) table is reducing**

Comment: I am not sure, but shouldn't the 2nd record, paid column, be 17500 now, because you paid 3000 + 14500?

Comment: @S-Man yes, the total paid for that item now is 17,500 but the amount being applied out of the 15,000 paid is 14,500. 15,000 was paid, 500 was applied to `item 1` and the balance of 14,500 all went into `item 2`. That 500, 14,500, etc is what I'm trying to capture

Comment: what's the difference between apply_payment and amount_applied?

Comment: @S-Man `apply_payment` is the ONE payment made by a client. `amount_applied` is how much actually went into each item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need for each row some aggregation over window from first to previous row (I assume the ordering is imposed by ids):

```
with t (id, item, amount, paid, apply_payment) as (
  select 1, 'item 1',   500,    0, 15000 union
  select 2, 'item 2', 20000, 3000, 15000 union
  select 3, 'item 3',  7000,    0, 15000
)
select id, item, amount, paid, apply_payment, amount - paid as really_remaining,
  greatest(apply_payment - coalesce(sum (amount - paid) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0), 0) as cash_before_this_row,
  least(amount - paid, greatest(apply_payment - coalesce(sum (amount - paid) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0), 0)) amount_applied
from t
order by id;
```

(I renamed `apply_payment` column to `cash_before_this_row` since the name `apply_payment` is used in source table but has different meaning in result.)

Comment: Thanks. This works exactly as desired. Didn't know about a couple of things you've done in the greatest and least functions. I'll have to look those up 

Comment: You are welcome :-) Please try to provide sample data as CTE directly in question next time. Also the query can be made more readable extracting columns up to `cash_before_this_row` into separate CTE and defining `amount_applied` as `least(really_remaining, cash_before_this_row)`

Comment: @TomášZáluský . . . Don't use `union`.  It adds unnecessary overhead to remove duplicates.  It is particularly unnecessary here where `VALUES()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Agree. Unions seemed to me as less typing in Intellij Idea rewriting ascii table to CTE, no other reason behind it :-) `select * from (values
    (1, 'item 1',   500,    0, 15000),
    (2, 'item 2', 20000, 3000, 15000),
    (3, 'item 3',  7000,    0, 15000)
  ) as t` is certainly more readable. Good point, thanks.